# AngularJS, link hijacking and HTML responses

Tags: angularjs

I've been through the AngularJS tutorials and perused a lot of documentation but I'm coming up short as to how to tie some pieces together in the "Angular way."

Here's the basic use case (largely determined by an existing product and CMS over which I have little control):

I'd like to be able to target a given area of the page and "hijack" the links there. When the user clicks a link, I need to fetch the contents of the `href` asynchronously (returns an HTML response) and then load that HTML payload into another area indicated in the link's `target` attribute.

So, given this example markup:

```
<div class="nav" hijack-links>
    <a target="mainContent" href="path/to/foo.html">Link 1</a>
    <a target="secondaryContent" href="path/to/bar.html">Link 1</a>
</div>

...

<div my-content-area="mainContent">

</div>

...

<div my-content-area="secondaryContent">

</div>
```

User clicks "Link 1", the contents of `path/to/foo.html` are fetched and then dropped into `mainContent`.

Is this even a good use case for Angular? I looked into the routing system but the links that need to be hijacked are extremely unpredictable and it seemed virtually impossible to predict the pattern.

**EDIT** 
Updated with [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RXCjvBmVuOZr5icaPA64?p=preview)

The Plunker shows what I was trying. I could use jQuery to dump the contents of the $http response into a target container, but that doesn't seem like the "Angular" way.

For what it's worth, this would be a retrofit on an existing site and CMS, hence the narrow requirements.

ngClick seems inconvenient as I can't necessarily attach it to every link. An indeterminate number of links can be inserted inside a container. I need to be able to catch any of them higher up the DOM rather than attaching individually.

Comment: You should change your attributes to "content-area" instead of "my-content-area" in order to match your Plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's a solution using `ngInclude`, which is the "angular way" to include content at a given url inside an element ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MGebkQNWvSlyosGbEXDV?p=preview)):

```
myApp.directive('contentArea', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      contentArea: '@'
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-include="$parent.hijackLinks[contentArea]"></div>'
  };
});

myApp.directive('hijackLinks', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.hijackLinks = {};
      element.bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.hijackLinks[e.target.target] = e.target.href;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

One issue with this solution is that it doesn't display the original content in the "content area" tags (thus making the transclude useless). One way around this is to change the template string to:

```
<div ng-transclude ng-if="!$parent.hijackLinks[contentArea]"></div>
<div ng-include="$parent.hijackLinks[contentArea]"></div>
```

I'm not sure I would call this an elegant solution, but it does use directives and the scope rather than DOM manipulation with jQuery.

Comment: Would it be safe to say this is a bad use case for AngularJS? I'm working with an existing CMS and have to keep the original HTML for SEO purposes.

Comment: I think using angular for something like this is fine, although it is a bit of a unique situation. I'm not sure whether it's better to use my solution or just do the DOM manipulation with jquery to be honest, but it does feel kind if nice having a fully angular-based solution. So I guess really, it's whatever feel right to you :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use the `ngClick` directive on the links to set a scope variable, and then use the `ngInclude` directive to asynchronously fetch and display an html page from the server:

```
<div class="nav">
  <a ng-click="mainContent = 'foo.html'" href="">Link 1</a>
  <a ng-click="secondaryContent = 'bar.html'" href="">Link 2</a>
</div>

<div ng-include="mainContent">
</div>

<div ng-include="secondaryContent">
</div>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nc7im6evFkWLSR2uwMTE?p=preview) is a working plunkr.

Comment: My Plunker above might help clarify. In that example I can see how I could update the content areas via jQuery, but that seems to go against the grain of what Angular is for.

Comment: Is the "target" attribute going to be on every link? I was thinking that since you appeared to be adding a "target" attribute to every link anyway, that you could just add ngClick instead. Could you clarify the constraints?

Comment: It may not be on every link. Basically I want to "hijack" (hate that term) every link within a given context. If the link has a target and that target's not `_self`, `_parent` or `_blank` then I want to insert the response into the container defined by `target`